# Doxygen Table drawing

Tags: doxygen

I would like to insert a ASCII art table (as below) in the documentation.
The Markdown feature of doxygen comes in the way and messes it all up.
I've tried to the HTML table and they are fine but the source document becomes unreadable then.

Can I somehow get doxygen not to process a section but still include it in the output file?
Similar to here where 4 blanks allow to to inserted already formatted text in fixed width font.

```
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
 |AUTO_NEW_OFF | Entry action            | LED_FLASH     |
 |             |                         | SEQ_OFF       |
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
 |             | eXit action             |               |
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
 |             |                         |               |
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
 | OFF         | SEQ complete            |               |
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
```

---

I think I can answer this myself already.

The Fenced Code Blocks ( 3 x ~) feature seems to work ok

```
~~~
|-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
| MAN_NEW_OFF | Entry action            | LED_FLASH     |
|             |                         | SEQ_OFF       |
|-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
~~~
```

Comment: More reference link:  [Markdown Extensions - tables]
http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/markdown.html

Answer (score 4):

An improvement on fenced code would be to surround the table with the doxygen commands `@verbatim` and `@endverbatim`.

If you use a "code" style, be that markdown's `~~~` or doxygen's `@code`, there's a chance that current or future versions of Doxygen will start trying to colour it in syntactically.

Comment: you can use `@code{.unparsed}` to prevent syntax highlighting